# How can i create a variable with the name of the substr i am looking for?

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, macros, substr

I am looking for a sort a macro that i could do under R, to create a variable from another one. I want to know if in the ZZZ variable, the string starts with a certain 3 first characters (by using the substr function). And so i would name the created variable by the name of the string that i am looking for. Some example to be more explicit :

My data is like:

| ZZZ |
| --- |
| M41 |
| M410 |
| M42 |
| F128 |

I would like to create a loop like this:

```
data$xxx = ifelse(substr(data$ZZZ,1,3)=="xxx",1 ,0)
```

And so the data after would look like :

| ZZZ | M41 | F12 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| M41 | 1 | 0 |
| M410 | 1 | 0 |
| M42 | 0 | 0 |
| F128 | 0 | 1 |

Because i must do it for more than a hundred times, so creating a loop would help to decrease the size of the program.

I don't know if we can be able to do this type of macros under R.

Thanks for reading,
BP

Comment: Why are there columns for M41 and F12, but not for M42?

Comment: Because i am not looking for this string. Over maybe thousands of possible codes, i am looking for some only, i don't want to check all of them

Comment: Make you example reproducible. Also, search `for loops`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Assuming the inputs in the Note at the end sapply over the target values.

```
cbind(dat, +sapply(target, `==`, substr(dat$ZZZ, 1, 3)))
```

giving:

```
   ZZZ M41 F12
1  M41   1   0
2 M410   1   0
3  M42   0   0
4 F128   0   1
```

**2)** If every element of ZZZ is to be used in a target then use
`target <- unique(substr(dat$ZZZ, 1, 3))` instead of the value for `target` shown in the Note.

**3)**  If every element of ZZZ is to be used in a target then another approach is:

```
res <- cbind(dat, model.matrix(~ substr(dat$ZZZ, 1, 3) + 0, dat))
names(res) <- sub(".*\\)", "", names(res))
res
```

giving:

```
   ZZZ F12 M41 M42
1  M41   0   1   0
2 M410   0   1   0
3  M42   0   0   1
4 F128   1   0   0
```

### Note

```
target <- c("M41", "F12")
dat <- structure(list(ZZZ = c("M41", "M410", "M42", "F128")),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```